# insert statement in mysql incrementing for each insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below are my mysql tables..

```
create table customer(
    CustId int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    FirstName varchar(100) default null,
    LastName varchar(100) default null,
    Gender varchar(40) default null,
    Category varchar(40) default null,
    DateOfBirth date default null,
    Age int(3)default null,
    LastUsed TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
);

create table address(
    Address_Id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    Address varchar(1000) default null,
    Country varchar(40) default null,
    State varchar (50) default null,
    city varchar(50)default null,
    PinCode varchar(20)default null,
    EmailId varchar(50)default null,
    ContactNo varchar(20) default null,
    MobileNo varchar(20) default null,
    CustId int default null,
    foreign key(CustId) references customer(CustId),
    LastUsed TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
);


create table username(
    User_Id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    UserName varchar(50)default null,
    CustId int default null,
    foreign key(CustId)references customer(CustId),
    LastUsed TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
);

create table affiliate(
    Affiliate_Id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    Address_Id int default null,
    foreign key(Address_Id) references address(Address_Id),
    LastUsed TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
);

create table userlogin(
    Login_Id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    UserName varchar(50) default null,
    PassWord varchar(50)default null,
    Category varchar(40)default null,
    LastUsed TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
);
```

Am trying to run this below query :

```
start transaction;
    insert into userlogin (UserName) select UserName from username where CustId=1;
    insert into userlogin (PassWord)value ('constant');
    insert into userlogin (Category) select Category from customer where CustId=1;
commit;
```

But for each insert its getting incremented how to do all the inserts to  sit in a single row...
Kindly guide me as am trying to get the database knowledge as a starter.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Here is a downvote for your writing quality.

Comment: @Re Captcha thank you for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this?

```
start transaction;
insert into userlogin (UserName, PassWord, Category) values ((select UserName from username where CustId=1), 'constant', (select Category from customer where CustId=1))
commit;
```

Comment: `start transaction;
    insert into userlogin (UserName, PassWord, Category) values ('(select UserName from username where CustId=1)', 'constant', '(select Category from customer where CustId=1)')
    commit;` i tried it with single quotes it was showing error let me try this

Comment: No single quotes around inner `select` statements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, there is any reason for using separate insert queries:

```
INSERT
INTO userlogin
  (
    UserName,
    PassWord,
    Category
  )
  VALUES
  (
    (SELECT UserName FROM username WHERE CustId=1
    ),
    'constant',
    (SELECT Category FROM customer WHERE CustId=1
    )
  )
```